# Router transtion bottom to top?

Tags: vue.js

Как реализовать анимацию перехода по роуту с низу к верху

```
<transition name="page" mode="out-in">
  <router-view></router-view>
</transition>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rpu356md/

Comment: не совсем понятно, что нужно) а https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html не подходит?

Comment: Нужно анимация перехода на другой роут - компонент (анимиция с низу к верху)